# Jad File Signature

Tags: java, jar, signature, jarsigner, jad

I want to sign jad files. I checked the internet for *.jad file signature. I found [this site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85095/How-to-Digitally-Sign-a-J2ME-Midlet)

I used this command for signing the jad file.

```
 Java -jar JadTool.jar -addcert -keystore <keystorename> -alias <aliasname> 
-storepass <password> -inputjad <input_jadfile> 
-outputjad <output_jadfile>
```

Under the "Add Signature to JAD" title in this url.

But I encountered this error

```
  Error parsing input JAD:
```

How do I know where the problem is?

Comment: I wrote wrong code.I changed code.I want to sign jad file

Answer (score 0):

You first need to create a certificate. You can make a self signed certificate using WTK or any other tool.
Once you have the certificate, you need to sign you jar using the certificate. Again, you can do this using WTK